# Msys2 included packages

Tags: msys2

Is there a way to find out what default packages are installed along with Msys2 installation. I see that there is openssh, curl, git installed which I didn't. If there is a list that would also be useful. The official base package repository has a long list with thousands of entry.

Comment: I guess this is a trivial question and everyone but me knows how to figure it out going by the downvote

Answer (score 2):

After installing MSYS2, run `pacman -Q` to list the packages that are installed.

Comment: Thank you. That was giving me the list of all packages, which also includes the packages I have installed.

Comment: So you need to run it immediately after installing MSYS2.